# Drawing a rectangle inside an oval doesn't give the desired result

Tags: android, android-xml

I tried to make a button wherein a square shape should be inside a circle shape. It works well on a square with a circle but not with the other way around and I wonder why. Here's my xml code so far for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="@dimen/tab_space" android:right="@dimen/tab_space">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#990000" android:endColor="#550000" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#110000" />

    </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="@dimen/tab_space" android:right="@dimen/tab_space">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ff0000" android:endColor="#990000" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#440000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It worked for me.

chat_icon.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding android:left="7pt" android:top="8pt" android:right="7pt" android:bottom="8pt"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@color/jade" android:width="2dip"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then, to use it in your layout, declare it as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chat_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/chat_icon"
    ------------------------------  />
```